# Two BlockingQueue in the same endless loop?

Tags: java, queue, blocking

I have a thread, that processes incomming messages (endless loop). For this, I use a BlockingQueue (Java), which works as quite nice. Now, I want to add a second processor in the same Class oder method. The problem now is, that in the endless loop i have this part

```
newIncomming = this.incommingProcessing.take();
```

This part blocks if the Queue is empty. I'm looking for a solution to process to queues in the same class. The second queue can only processed, it some data is coming in for the first Queue.
Is there a way to handle tow blocking queues in the same endless loop?

Comment: Do you mean you want to process 2 blocking queues in one thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need two threads or you need them to share the same blocking queue. (Or you need to use a different structure than blocking queue)

Answer (score 0):

BlockingQueue is meant for multiple thread implementations.  Instead, use a simple Queue.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358457/where-should-you-use-blockingqueue-implementations-instead-of-simple-queue-implem).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if you do not want the thread to block on the queue if it is empty, you can use [BlockingQueue.peek()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek%28%29) to first check if the queue is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question I came up with the following

### Code snippet

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package blockingqueues;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 *
 * @author alfred
 */
public class BlockingQueues {
    private static String take(BlockingQueue<String> bq) {
        try {
            return bq.take();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final BlockingQueue<String> b1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        final BlockingQueue<String> b2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        es.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    String results = take(b1);
                    if (results == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("first: " + results);
                }
            }
        });
        es.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    String results = take(b2);
                    if (results == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("second: " + results);
                }
            }
        });
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in)
                );
        String input = null;
        System.out.println("type x to quit.");
        while (!"x".equals(input)) {
            input = br.readLine();
            if (input.startsWith("1 ")) {
                // Add something to first blocking queue.
                b1.add(input.substring(2));   
            } else if (input.startsWith("2 ")) {
                // Add something to second blocking queue.
                b2.add(input.substring(2));
            }
        }
        es.shutdownNow();
        es.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("bye!");
        br.close();
    }
}
```

### Executing program:

You can enter text from console to add task to  blockingqueue `b1` or `b2`. If your console `input` starts with a `1` like for example `input = "1 hello"` then the `b1` will process task(print `first: hello`) else if input starts with a `2` like for example `input = "world"` then b2 will print `second: world`.